# My nested relationship is switching the ids of the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to delete an attachment from my rails project. I have the attachment nested under test_suite. When I hit the attachment delete button, the generated url switch the ids of attachment and test_suite. ex. the url should be localhost:3000/test_suites/3/attachments/11 but I'm getting localhost:3000/test_suites/11/attachmnts/3 and I get the error that attachment id=3 doesn't exist which is right because it should be attachment id = 11

Here is how I set it up. 
routes.rb:

```
  resources :test_suites do
    resources :attachmnts, :only => [:create, :new, :destroy]
  end
```

model/test_suite.rb:

```
class TestSuite < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :attachemnts
end
```

model/attachment.rb:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :test_suite
    has_attached_file :attach

    validates_attachment_content_type :attach, :content_type => ["text/xml", "text/plain","text/html"]
end
```

I'm creating new attachment in test_suite show.The attachment will have a test_suite_id attribute. 
test_suites_controller.rb:

```
def show
        # create a variable pammed to test_suite with id passed from previous page
        @test_suite = TestSuite.find(params[:id])

        @attachment = Attachment.new
        @attachment.test_suite_id = @test_suite.id
    end
```

test_suite/show.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Type</th>
        <th>File Size</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <%= render partial: 'attachment', locals: {test_suite: @test_suite} %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

attachments/_attachment.html.erb:

```
<% test_suite.attachemnts.each do |attachment| %>
<tr>
    <td> <%=attachment.attach_file_name %> </td>
    <% if attachment.attach_content_type == 'text/plain'%>
        <td>txt</td>
    <% else %>
        <td><%= attchement.attach_content_type.split('/').last %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= attachement.attach_file_size %></td>
    <td><%= attachement.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>'.html_safe, test_suite_attachment_path(attachment),class:"btn btn-lg", method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the file?"} %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

My rails routes outputs:

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                            Controller#Action
                      root GET    /                                                      test_suites#index
   test_suite_attachements POST   /test_suites/:test_suite_id/attachements(.:format)     attachements#create
new_test_suite_attachement GET    /test_suites/:test_suite_id/attachements/new(.:format) attachements#new
    test_suite_attachement DELETE /test_suites/:test_suite_id/attachements/:id(.:format) attachements#destroy
               test_suites GET    /test_suites(.:format)                                 test_suites#index
                           POST   /test_suites(.:format)                                 test_suites#create
            new_test_suite GET    /test_suites/new(.:format)                             test_suites#new
           edit_test_suite GET    /test_suites/:id/edit(.:format)                        test_suites#edit
                test_suite GET    /test_suites/:id(.:format)                             test_suites#show
                           PATCH  /test_suites/:id(.:format)                             test_suites#update
                           PUT    /test_suites/:id(.:format)                             test_suites#update
                           DELETE /test_suites/:id(.:format)                             test_suites#destroy
```

Comment: I see a typos in the word 'attachments' but in your routes.rb. Please update your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with a nested object, you need the ids of both the parent and child object to perform show/edit/update/destroy operations. The issue is because you're not passing the `test_suite` object to `test_suite_attachment_path` helper. Modify your link to

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>'.html_safe, test_suite_attachement_path(test_suite, attachment),class:"btn btn-lg", method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the file?"} %>
```

You can also pass an array of the parent and child objects instead of using the path helper.

```
#[test_suite, attachment]

<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>'.html_safe, [test_suite, attachment], class:"btn btn-lg", method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the file?"} %>
```

> Please use a consistent spelling of 'attachments'. You're using a different version in every place.